Control output of zypper search, packages, etc
I am trying to retrieve the output of zypper search in a particular format.
When I run zypper search on my repo with the following command: zypper search --details --repo my_repo_alias, I get an output that looks like this:
 | Mesa                                  | package    | 22.3.5-150500.75.2                       | x86_64 | my_repo_alias
  | Mesa                                  | srcpackage | 22.3.5-150500.75.2                       | noarch | my_repo_alias
  | Mesa-dri                              | package    | 22.3.5-150500.75.2                       | x86_64 | my_repo_alias
  | Mesa-drivers                          | srcpackage | 22.3.5-150500.75.2                       | noarch | my_repo_alias
  | Mesa-gallium                          | package    | 22.3.5-150500.75.2                       | x86_64 | my_repo_alias
  | Mesa-libEGL1                          | package    | 22.3.5-150500.75.2                       | x86_64 | my_repo_alias
  | Mesa-libGL1                           | package    | 22.3.5-150500.75.2                       | x86_64 | my_repo_alias
  | Mesa-libglapi0                        | package    | 22.3.5-150500.75.2                       | x86_64 | my_repo_alias

However, I need to get the above info in this format:
Mesa-22.3.5-150500.75.2.x86_64.rpm
Mesa-22.3.5-150500.75.2.noarch.rpm
Mesa-dri-22.3.5-150500.75.2.x86_64.rpm
Mesa-drivers-22.3.5-150500.75.2.noarch.rpm
Mesa-gallium-22.3.5-150500.75.2.x86_64.rpm
Mesa-libEGL1-22.3.5-150500.75.2.x86_64.rpm
Mesa-libGL1-22.3.5-150500.75.2.x86_64.rpm
Mesa-libglapi0-22.3.5-150500.75.2.x86_64.rpm

Currently, to do this I'm using this code:
while IFS= read -r line; do
    package_name=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
    package_version=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $6}')
    package_arch=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $8}')
    concatenated_info="$package_name-$package_version.$package_arch.rpm"
done < <(zypper search --details --repo sles_base_os_repo)

I think this is not ideal as this is using the position of certain fields (name, version, arch) to retrieve the necessary info to make the concatenated string. While unlikely, the position of these fields might be subject to change which would break the code.
I have been looking the zypper command to see if there is a way I can control how the above info is outputted but haven't found anything yet. Is anyone aware of something that might be available with zypper that would allow me to output the above info without needing to use the awk command I have currently?
